# C - manipulating pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I have the beginning part of a function below.   I don't have to code in C often so I am very rusty.  I have a parameter called arguments.  arguments will come in as " 10000 a" for example.  I am trying to use a temporary pointer to get to the second parameter.  My issue is temp doesn't seem to move or change at all when I add to it or even just try and set it.  Below are the results of the print statements if i were to run this

arguments address : 61fea4 and value of ifNum: 1

temp before add 1 : 61fe84

temp before loop : 61fe84

temp after loop : 61fe84

What am i doing wrong?  why isn't temp the same as arguments when it is set to it?

```
int mem_set(Cmd *cp, char *arguments){
    char *p;
    char *temp;

  int ifNum = sscanf(arguments,"%x",&p);
  printf(" arguments address : %x and value of ifNum: %d\n",&arguments, ifNum);
  temp = &arguments;
  printf(" temp before add 1 : %x\n",&temp);
  temp = &arguments + 1;
  printf(" temp before loop : %x\n",&temp);
  while(*temp != ' '){
    temp++;
  }
```

Comment: That should be `printf(" temp before add 1 : %p\n", temp);`  (without the ampersand). What you're printing is the address of the pointer, which doesn't change.

Comment: `sscanf(arguments, "%x", &p);` causes undefined behaviour. The `%x` specifier scans an `unsigned int` but you did not provide the address of an unsigned int variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see any change because you're printing the address of your `temp` variable.
Using the operator `&` you get the address of variable not its value.
Anyway your error seems to be that you think that to use a pointer you have alway to prefix it with the `&` operator.
You specify that a variable is a pointer just declaring it as that `int *p;` then you have simply to use it. Now to equal a pointer to another you have to simply assign it like `int *p = p1;`.
Your code then will be:

```
int mem_set(Cmd *cp, char *arguments){
    char p[100];    //You need an array here because you are storing data
    char *temp;

  int ifNum = sscanf(arguments,"%x",p);
  printf(" arguments address : %x and value of ifNum: %d\n",arguments, ifNum);
  temp = arguments;
  printf(" temp before add 1 : %x\n",temp);
  temp = arguments + 1;
  printf(" temp before loop : %x\n",temp);
  while(*temp != ' '){
    temp++;
  }
```

Comment: I didn't use your code line for line but your description above helped me understand the difference between using the & operator and not.  I was confused on thinking the address of the pointer and the value of the pointer which is an address were the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If this clarified your problem please accept the answer to close the question. And another point have you understand the change of `char *p` to `char p[100]`? a pointer do not allocate any memory for effective data, but is just a variable that holds an address. But if you use sscanf to store something you have to initialize the pointer to a valid address or declare it as a valid variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int mem_set(Cmd *cp, char *arguments){
    int p;
    char *temp;

    // Need to store hex value in an int so we need a pointer to an int
    int ifNum = sscanf(arguments, "%x", &p);
    printf(" arguments address : %p and value of ifNum: %d\n", arguments, ifNum);
    // We want a temporary pointer that points to the same memory as arguments
    temp = arguments;
    printf(" temp before loop : %p\n", temp);
    // Find the end of the hex value
    while (*temp != ' ') {
        temp++;
    }
}
```

Without comments from you, it is hard to guess what you are trying to do here. However, this code will at least let you capture the hex value at the start of arguments and show you how to initialize and manipulate temp.